# import rclpy without sourcing setup.bash

Tags: python, ros2, bash, module, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use the rclpy module in a python script. This script is called by a flask application which is invoked by an apache2 webserver and does not get the necessary bash context.
When I run the python script from bash with python3 foo.py everything works fine, as I have . /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash in my ~/.bashrc .

When the script gets invoked by flask and apache2, import rclpy is not found.
Exeucting `sys.path.insert("/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/")` brings another error:

```
The C extension '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/_rclpy.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so' failed to be imported while being present on the system. Please refer to 'https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Troubleshooting/Installation-Troubleshooting/#import-failing-even-with-library-present-on-the-system' for possible solutions
```

There has been a similar [Thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/306509/rclpy-import-in-application-fails/) with no solution. The essence seems to be that opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash does more than just setting paths.

Now, is there any possibilty to use rclpy in a python script **without** sourcing from bash?
Thanks

Ubuntu 20.04
ROS2 foxy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375628/import-rclpy-without-sourcing-setup.bash/) by [highmax1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/71214/highmax1234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2021-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As part of my GSoC project, I had researched and resolved the same problem. My findings and solutions are mentioned in [my GSoC blog post](https://theroboticsclub.github.io/gsoc2021-Siddharth_Saha/2021/06/22/bashrc-start-sh)

For completeness, I will cover the main points here.
When you invoke the script via flask and apache2, the ~/.bashrc does get sourced but suffers an early exit due to the following lines-

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

You're running it using a non-interactive terminal. Thus `"$PS1"` is not set.

The bash script you mentioned in the other answer is quite acceptable but it's useful to know the root of the problem. I have included more links in my blog post if you'd like to understand this better.

---

Originally posted by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) with karma: 156 on 2021-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1